# Finding the permutation that shows two permutations are conjugates method?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Problem:
Given $\sigma=(12)(34)$ and $\gamma=(56)(13)$ find $\tau\in S_6$ with 
$\tau^{-1}\sigma\tau=\gamma$

Attempt: I'm kind of new to this but from what I understanding find $\tau$ that satisfies this will show that $\sigma$~$\gamma$ right? This means that they are conjugates of each other. I started off by writing out what the permutations are in $S_6$ but I was not seeing anything. I also rewrote what we are trying to prove as $\sigma\tau$=$\tau\gamma$ by left multiplying by $\tau$.

Question: My main question is whether or not there's a method to solving these types of problems and if there is how can it be applied to this one? Any step in the right direction is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: for any cycle $(i_1\,i_2\,\ldots\,i_k)$, we have
$$
\sigma (i_1\,i_2\,\ldots\,i_k)\sigma^{-1}=(\sigma(i_1)\,\sigma(i_2)\,\ldots\,\sigma(i_k))
$$
for all $\sigma\in S_n$.

Comment: I thought a permutation times its inverse gives back the original set. So for 1...6 if I do $\sigma\sigma^{-1}$ that gives back 1...6?

Comment: I've clarified above.

Comment: Ah okay, I understand now, thank you. I believe this also implies that we want $\tau$ such that $\sigma=((\tau(5)\tau(6))(\tau(1)\tau(3))$ and you find a permutation that matches those conditions.